# Can't pull Java 8 image from Docker

Tags: java, docker

I can not pull **Java 8** image from **Docker**, this problem occurred yesterday evening probably *Oracle* has changed repo of Java 8 I'm not sure. I get the following error:

```
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-11-02 09:48:41--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 93.186.137.138, 93.186.137.153
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|93.186.137.138|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-11-02 09:48:41--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 104.86.229.143, 2a02:26f0:c00:4bd::2d3e, 2a02:26f0:c00:48f::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.86.229.143|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1509616242_c2c10a584fa09bff72a90cbe16357500 [following]
--2017-11-02 09:48:42--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1509616242_c2c10a584fa09bff72a90cbe16357500
Reusing existing connection to download.oracle.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-11-02 09:48:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt-get clean
......
```

Comment: Why do you use `ubuntu:15.04` as the parent? If you use a newer release, Java 8 should already be in the repos. Also, there are also some ready-made Java 8 images available; do you have to base this on Ubuntu and install manually at all?

Comment: It turned out the problem occurred because of ubuntu version I changed to 16.04 and it worked.

Comment: why don't you go with official openJDK (or lighter OpenJDK - JRE if you don't have JSPs) docker image, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: If you're goal is to have a Docker container, why not use the openjdk official image instead? https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu version is the problematic part so I changed to **16.04** and it worked. It's better to have *latest* Ubuntu version.